# Is there any sense in which 'enumerable' is distinct from 'denumerable'?

Tags: etymology, synonyms

Oxford English Dictionary has

> ▪ I. enumerable, a.
> (ɪˈnjuːmərəb(ə)l)
> [f. enumerate v. + -able.]
> That can be enumerated; having a definite number; numerable; spec. in Math. = denumerable a.
> Hence eˈnumerably adv.

Notice that *'spec. in Math. = denumerable'*, which is the context in which my question arose. I learned enumerable when I was in school and have only just encountered 'denumerable' in a textbook.

> denumerable, a. Math.
> (dɪˈnjuːmərəb(ə)l)
> [f. denumerate v. + -able. Cf. G. abzählbar, Fr. dénombrable.]
> Of a set: infinite but countable; capable of being put into a one-to-one correspondence with the set of finite integers or natural numbers; also more widely, either finite or countably infinite; enumerable a.
> C. S. Peirce used the term in a different sense.
> Hence deˈnumerably adv.

Is there any daylight between these two terms? It looks like 'enumerable' comes from the English verb 'enumerate', which comes from Latin

> II. enumerate, v.
> (ɪˈnjuːməreɪt)
> [f. L. ēnumerāt- ppl. stem of ēnumerāre, f. ē out + numerāre to count, f. numerus number.]

whereas 'denumerate' gets its 'de' from French. So did English just end up with two copies of this word?

Comment: There seem to be *numerable* words to express the same idea.  Sorry, couldn't help myself.  I think that in general usage no difference between *enumerable* and *denumerable* but general usage may not be an accurate guide for their deployment in mathematics and computer science.

Comment: @High Performance Mark 'enumerable and denumerable' and 'in general usage' appear to me to be strange bedfellows. And checking Google 1-grams for 'enumerable',  'denumerable' and 'number', and checking actual examples for sources, would seem to endorse this.

Comment: Enumerate is far more common than denumerate, according to Google NGrams, and enumerable somewhat more common than denumerable (although with very rare words I'm not sure how reliable NGrams is). In general usage, enumerate/enumerable would therefore be better, being as in general usage they're synonyms, but as for math, you're on your own.

Comment: Perhaps a mathematician could tell us if the cardinality of the infinite set of natural numbers is denumerable but not enumerable, which might be the only significant difference, and isn't relevant to most of us.

Comment: The terms are used interchangeably in mathematics, though individuals have their own favorites for their own reasons, as usual.